# JavaScript: Is there way to create a named JSON object from a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Consider the following:

I have a string:

`April-3-2020`

And an array:

`var myArray = []`

How can I make a labeled JSON object e.g. `April-3-2020` be pushed into the array to produce this JSON?

myArray will contain:

```
[
    "April-3-2020" : {
                      "some_property_for_april_3_2020": "that data",
                      "some_other_property_for_april_3_2020": "this data",
                      },

    "April-4-2020" : {
                      "some_property_for_april_4_2020": "that data",
                      "some_other_property_for_april_4_2020": "this data",
                      },
]
```

myArray is an array of JSON objects...

Comment: That's invalid JSON.

Comment: Use object.. Array can have number as key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should either use Map or Array of Objects for this.

for Example if it is **Map**:

```
{
"April-3-2020" : {
                      "some_property_for_april_3_2020": "that data",
                      "some_other_property_for_april_3_2020": "this data",
                 },

"April-4-2020" : {
                      "some_property_for_april_4_2020": "that data",
                      "some_other_property_for_april_4_2020": "this data",
                 }
}
```

or **Array of Object**:

```
[
  {
     "id/key": "April-3-2020",
     "some_property_for_april_3_2020": "that data",
     "some_other_property_for_april_3_2020": "this data"
  }
]
```

Comment: This is a great solution! Thank you my friend!